# Show Woocommerce order details on custom thank you page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hi I created custom thank you page for my COD (cash on delivery) payment option. Redirect code below working.

```html
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'thankyou_custom_payment_redirect');
    function thankyou_custom_payment_redirect(){
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) {
        global $wp;

        // Get the order ID
        $order_id =  intval( str_replace( 'checkout/order-received/', '', $wp->request ) );

        // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

        // Set HERE your Payment Gateway ID
        if( $order->get_payment_method() == 'cod' ){

            // Set HERE your custom URL path
            wp_redirect( home_url( '/custom-page/' ) );
            exit(); // always exit
        }
    }
}
```

Now in my `/custom-page/` I want to display same details as in Woocommerce `order-details.php`. I created `custom-page.php` with(`/* Template Name: COD Thank you page */`) for my Thank you Page, copied code from original Woocommerce `order-details.php` but just loads blank page. Can someone help me to do this correctly please.
Thank you

Answer (score -2):

Ensure that your new order-details.php has a URL and that that URL is added inside of WooCommerce > Settings > Advanced > Order Received. In there you would add the slug of that URL of your new order-details page.
There are also easier ways to create a custom thank you page using plugins such as this one: https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-custom-thank-you-page-for-woocommerce/

Comment: Hi Standard woocomerce order received page I using for Credit/Debit Card payment option. Pay By COD is extra payment option with custom Thank you page. As I understand I can't use multiple "slug"  in WooCommerce > Settings > Advanced > Order Received?

Comment: You can redirect depending on the product purchased or payment method. See more here:  https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/thank-you-page.html#redirects

Comment: Hi Yes I know my Redirect works no problem at all. I just want to display order details on my custom Thank you Page not sure how to achieve this.